# Hibernate @ManyToOne - only one direction relation

Tags: hibernate

I got classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User{

private Integer id;
private String name;
private Address address; 
}
```

and:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="adress")
    public class Adress{

        private Integer id;
        private String street;
        (...)
}
```

Any way how to map relation @ManyToOne (many users can have the same adres), BUT I don't want to have property List< User > users in my Address class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the annotation `@ManyToOne` to the address field. Problem solved. For details on how this can be customized, see the [Hibernate reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7576). Typically you would use

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "addressId")
private Address address;
```

Comment: Hi JB
Can you please help me in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895585/hibernate-version-annotation-and-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instanc