# Hibernate @Version annotation and object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

My New Project is in Hibernate 4.2.5.Final and Spring. After Login, I am storing the user object in the session. 
Now after successful login, I need to insert one record in the application log. Here are the classes:

Class BaseEntity

```
 @MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ID;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    private Long createdBy;
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;
    private Long updatedBy;
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedDate;
    private String deactivatedReason;
    private String activatedReason;
    private Integer active;

    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Long getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Long getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(Long updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public String getDeactivatedReason() {
        return deactivatedReason;
    }

    public void setDeactivatedReason(String deactivatedReason) {
        this.deactivatedReason = deactivatedReason;
    }

    public String getActivatedReason() {
        return activatedReason;
    }

    public void setActivatedReason(String activatedReason) {
        this.activatedReason = activatedReason;
    }

    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

Class Users:

```
package com.product.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.product.audit.IAuditLog;
import com.product.domain.base.BaseEntity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findUserByUserID", query = "SELECT usr  FROM Users  as usr WHERE usr.userName = ? and usr.practice.code = ?") })
public class Users extends BaseEntity implements IAuditLog {


    private String userName;
    private String password;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Practice
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "practiceID")
    private Practice practice;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Class ApplicationEvents:

```
package com.product.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "applicationevents")
public class ApplicationEvents {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ID;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date eventDate;
    private String comments;
    private Integer eventType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "practiceID")
    private Practice practice;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID")
    private Users userID;

    //getters and setters

}

ApplicationEvents appEvent = new ApplicationEvents();
        appEvent.setEventType(eventType);
        appEvent.setPractice(practice);
        appEvent.setUserID(userID);
        appEvent.setComments(comments);
        appEvent.setEventDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        CRUDService.Save(appEvent);
```

When I try to save ApplicationEvent, I am getting the following error:

```
18:34:34.540 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] INFO  c.p.a.MyUserDetailsService - Logged User authentication sucess. UserName admin and practice Name Physicians Choice Laboratory
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.product.domain.ApplicationEvents
        */ insert 
        into
            applicationevents
            (comments, eventDate, eventType, practiceID, userID) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
19 Sep, 2013 6:34:34 PM org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall call:117
SEVERE: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.product.domain.Users; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.product.domain.Users
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:680)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:562)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
```

Very Important Note:
When I remove the @Version in the base entity, everything works fine.

Comment: Where does the `Users` object come from exactly? If you are pulling the User from the session, at that moment in time it is detached from the persistence context and considered transient. See [Persistence Contexts](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch03.html). You would need to do a `merge` or `saveOrUpdate` on the `Users` object to re-attach it to the persistence context as @Prabhakaran suggests.

Comment: Let me re-state that... the `Users` object is transient if it is being pulled from the session, not detached. Detached objects are slightly different than transient objects [Working with objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html).

Comment: Yes User Object is coming from the session and as you said it is in transient state. But i am just wonder, how the problem does not occur when i remove @version in baseentity ? And also i am afraid of saving user object using saveupdate or merge, because we have audit log for each table

Comment: I am really afraid of my detail tables. since my one of the detail tables contain related to more than 10 master tables. So all those as referred as foreign key to the detail table, so if this is the case, do i need to do merge for all the 10 master first and then save detail table ?

Comment: The `@Version` annotation is meant to prevent exactly what you are worried about. If there was a concurrent modification of the `Users` object it will throw an exception during flush [Optimistic concurrency control](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-optimistic). As to why you don't get an exception if you remove `@Version`... it's probably because hibernate is not doing a version check in that case and therefore goes back to 'last-commit-wins' mode.

Comment: Ok what is the alternate method by keeping @version and not saving the user object, but insert one record into detail table application events ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37665/discussion-between-senthil-muthiah-and-fgreg)

Comment: Please help to resolve my problem

Comment: It is my mistake. In the users table, the particular record version column has null value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982948/hibernate-version-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the user.

```
        CRUDService.Save(userID);
```

Then you associate user to the ApplicationEvents

```
        ApplicationEvents appEvent = new ApplicationEvents();
        appEvent.setEventType(eventType);
        appEvent.setPractice(practice);
        appEvent.setUserID(userID);
        appEvent.setComments(comments);
        appEvent.setEventDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        CRUDService.Save(appEvent);
```

Comment: I dont want to save the user, because there is no change. Once again, userID is a object of users class which is obtained from the login controller.

Comment: In the application event table, userid is just a foreign key

Comment: Very Important Note: When I remove the @Version in the base entity, everything works fine.

Comment: I tried the following http://parasjain.net/2008/01/14/orghibernatetransientobjectexception-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-before-flushing/#comment-427